# Should we use parentheses or brackets around functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Should we use parentheses or brackets around functions? Is there a widely accepted rule/style?

For example, which of the following is the preferred way of writing formulas?

$(f(x) + g(x)) * h(x)$

vs

$[f(x) + g(x)] * h(x)$

Comment: Parentheses are most common.  But why do you care?

Comment: Wikipedia has gone so far as to say the square brackets are incorrect.

Comment: @MattSamuel I'm curious to know the reasoning behind this

Comment: Maybe $\bigl(f(x)+g(x)\bigr)\cdot h(x)$

Comment: @Rhys Well, outside of elementary school textbooks, I have never seen them used in place of parentheses to group terms.

Comment: Brackets and braces were once (in the manual typewriter days) helpful in distinguishing the various levels of nested grouping. They are no longer necessary, since modern typesetting tools allow us to distinguish those levels with differently-sized parentheses. Nowadays, brackets can actually be confusing, since they are often used to indicate special functions (such as the rounding, floor, or ceiling functions, although the latter two now have specially-typeset forms, too).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks. I'd like to know the recommended way and stick to it in my academic writings.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Seems there's a consensus that parentheses are preferred and bigger parentheses if possible.

Comment: Disagree. Unless it has special significance in context, the choice of grouping symbol is useful to visually distinguish particular groups. This applies to sizes of parentheses as well, but square and curly braces stand out especially well and draw the eye readily. Of more concern to me is your use of an asterisk to represent what I presume is multiplication—this is entirely unacceptable where “$\cdot$” and “$\times$” (and plain juxtaposition) are available. This is mathematics, not C.

Comment: @MPW Err... I admit I was sloppy when making that example, and I did not know it will be rendered as LaTeX. But, as an excuse, it doesn't have to be multiplication. We have the convolution operation right?

Comment: @alick: Quite so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From *Mathematical Writing*, by (the!) Donald Knuth, (the!) Tracy Larrabee, and (the!) Paul M. Roberts (1987):

> In some cases your audience may expect nested parentheses. [... S]hould the outer pair be changed to brackets (or curly-braces)? This was once the prevailing convention, but it is now not only obsolete but potentially dangerous; brackets and curly braces have semantic content for many scientific professionals. [...] Typographers help by using slightly larger parentheses for the outer pair in a nested set.

This passage occurs as part of a discussion about parenthetical remarks *in text*, but I believe the sentiment applies (and is *intended* to apply) to displayed formulas.

As the creator of [$\TeX$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX), Knuth may have been a *little* biased about what counted as "obsolete" typographic practice. Nevertheless, the opinion seems fairly widespread these days, and I suspect that this is the thinking behind Wikipedia's no-brackets guideline.

A not-unrelated passage from later in the book (bear in mind that the anecdotes date back more than three decades) ...

> Don [Knuth] showed us [Larrabee and Roberts, as note-takers in Knuth's Mathematical Writing class] two examples where mathematical journals had trouble presenting programs, algorithms, or concrete mathematics in papers he wrote. [...] Don had to convince the typesetters at *Acta Arithmetica* to create "floor" and "ceiling" functions by carving off small pieces of the metal type for square brackets. [The second example had to do with "$:=$".]
>
> [...]
>
> He didn't get his way on everything, though. Brackets were used interchangeably with parentheses in a mathematical formula, despite Don's protest that the former have special meanings.

---

I'll note that I don't always find that "slightly larger parentheses" are *enough* to make nested groups legible; I sometimes feather my nests with spaces. I might consider formatting the example in the question as
$$\big(\,f(x)+g(x)\,\big)\cdot h(x) \quad\text{rather than}\quad \big(f(x)+g(x)\big)\cdot h(x)$$
In this case, though, it doesn't seem to make an appreciable difference.

---

Incidentally, the *Journal of Machine Learning Research* makes a [PDF of *Mathematical Writing*](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf) available.